# Can I bundle items that are published within the feature time interval in Rxjava2?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

toList () releases all the items that can be published, but I want to combine the items published for a certain time and release them at that time.

Here is how I originally implemented it.

```
        val queue = LinkedBlockingQueue<Int>()
        val random = Random()
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()

        (0..10).toObservable()
                .concatMap { item ->
                    Observable.just(item)
                            // Use delay to represent random work time.
                            .delay((random.nextLong() % 10) * 20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                }
                .subscribe { item -> queue.add(item) }

        Observable.interval(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
                .filter { queue.isNotEmpty() }
                .map {
                    val list = ArrayList<Int>()
                    var item = queue.poll()
                    while (item != null) {
                        list.add(item)
                        item = queue.poll()
                    }
                    list
                }
                .subscribe {
                    Log.i("Test", "${System.currentTimeMillis() - start} - ${it.joinToString(",")}")
                }

I/Test: 163 - 0,1,2
I/Test: 212 - 3
I/Test: 412 - 4
I/Test: 463 - 5,6,7
I/Test: 613 - 8,9
I/Test: 763 - 10
```

I used a scan to create a separate Queue and avoid having two Observables refer to it.

```
        (0..10).toObservable()
                .concatMap {
                    Observable.just(listOf(it))
                            // Use delay to represent random work time.
                            .delay((random.nextLong() % 10) * 20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                }
                // Every 50 milliseconds, bundle items that have not yet been subscribed.
                .scan { t1: List<Int>, t2: List<Int> ->
                    t1 + t2
                }
                .debounce(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                //Outputs the published item.
                .subscribe {
                    Log.i("Test", "${System.currentTimeMillis() - start} - ${it.joinToString(",")}")
                }

I/Test: 160 - 0,1,2
I/Test: 261 - 0,1,2,3
I/Test: 442 - 0,1,2,3,4,5
I/Test: 623 - 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
I/Test: 743 - 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
I/Test: 819 - 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

The intervals for each issuance time are also unstable (when using queue, it is output in 50ms interval, but when using scan (), unexpected time interval occurs such as 70ms), and the previously released items are output again.

If I want to bundle and release items that are issued within a certain time interval, is there anything other than using Queue?

Comment: There are the buffer() operators you should check out.